# How to copy the contents of a single cell from one Google spreadsheet to another Google Speadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to copy the content of one cell of a Google speadsheet to another cell in a different Google spreadsheet. I have tried the formula

```
(=Exportrange("spreadsheet-key", "Sheet-name! range"))
```

But it is not working. Probably because my formula looks like

```
(=Exportrange("Spreadsheet name", "Sheet-name! C19:C19"))
```

Looking for a solution on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "exportrange" in Google Sheets.

Use [`importrange`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) where the first parameter is the URL of the spreadsheet, from which the data is to be taken, and the second points to a cell. It will look like this, where ... depends on the source spreadsheet:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit#gid=0", "Sheet1!A1")
```

The first time importrange is used, it displays #REF! message. Hover over it to see a prompt to allow import; this only happens once for a given pair of spreadsheets.